# Apache Zeppelin - modify default syntax highlight

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, syntax-highlighting, apache-zeppelin

I am using **Zeppelin** (*ver. 0.6.0.*) along with **Spark** (*ver. 1.6.1.*) and **Hadoop** (*ver. 2.6.*).

Zeppelin gives users option to use several interpreters, but I decided to exclusively use Python.

I managed to set my default interpreter to **org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter**. By creating *zeppelin-site.xml* file from template; and putting PySparkInterpreter in front of org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter inside zeppelin.interpreters  property tag.

So far everything works correctly. I don't have to insert *%pyspark* at top of every cell in order write Python code.

**Problem:**
Syntax highlight of code which is used is for Scala.

In order to have Python syntax highlight I have to do:

1. Empty content of cell (copy it)
2. Insert only %pyspark and press SHIFT + ENTER
3. Wait for error to occur and paste code back into cell.

**Question:**
Where can I modify default syntax highlight for Zeppelin notebook and set it to use Python one?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely will be possible once 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-139
is resolved.